# Laravel Websockets issues - Public events working but not private - Getting 401 error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel on a NON spa app with vue 3.
I am also using Sanctum for an API but do not use it for the non SPA communications.

When I broadcast a public websocket event, I receive it in the front end, but wow! I cannot at all pass a single private event, nothing received in the front end:

Here is my code:

Event sent form my controller:

```
        $text = text::where('text_name', $updatetext)->first();

        if ($text) {
            $text->update([
                'data1' => $data1,
                'data2' => $data1,
            ]);

            $userIds = $text->users->pluck('id')->toArray();

            // Trigger the event with the keyword ID and user IDs
            event(new textUpdated($text->id, $userIds));
```

Event IDs received:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class textUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public int $tries = 2;

    public int $textId;
    public array $userIds;


     */
    public function __construct(int $textId, array $userIds)
    {
        $this->textId = $textId;
        $this->userIds = $userIds;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        // Create private channels for each user ID in the array
        $channels = [];

        foreach ($this->userIds as $userId) {
            $channels[] = new PrivateChannel("user.{$userId}");
        }
        return $channels;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            'textId' => $this->textId
        ];
    }


    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'text.updated';
    }
}
```

Channell.php:

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
});
```

in vue js:

```
 created() {
        window.Echo.private('user.' + this.userId)
            .listen('.text.updated', (event) => {
                console.log(event.textId); //Nothing received
            });
}
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot this please?

It is strange that this only fails with private channels and not public.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you bypass your authentication from `return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;` to `return true;` ? Also, which request gives the 401?

Comment: Try debug or dd()?  Under broadcast::chanell() in channell.php file, if you reached there ?

Comment: Are you uncomment BroadcastServiceProvider and add auth routes? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#broadcast-service-provider

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally found the issue after a week battle.....I had this set:
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
When I replaced it by:
 Broadcast::routes();


It started to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change this:
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);

To
Broadcast::routes();

In the BroadcastServiceProvider.php